# Cloning large data structure ReactJS makes value go missing

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, sorting, destructuring

Hullo there, I have an array which each value has a deep Tree object. I'm keeping a version of this in a useState hook and another in a useRef. My idea is to make the changes on the ref and therefore update the state.
My problems started on keeping the array ordered, so I added an order key to sort it.

This is a wrapper function to update the state, it isn't sorting nor cloning (either shallow or deep) the array makes the last value disappear

```js
  const updateScope = (newScopes = null as ScopesProps[]) => {
    if (newScopes) {
      scopesRef.current = newScopes;
    }

    const supposedToBeSorted = scopesRef.current.sort(
      (a, b) => a.order - b.order
    );

    console.log("aha, gotcha", supposedToBeSorted, [...supposedToBeSorted]);

    setScopes([...supposedToBeSorted]);
  };
```

And this is what I got logged

```
aha, gotcha 
[{…}]
0: {id: 110134, main: {…}, loaded: false, reorderCriteria: '', order: 1}
1: {id: 107950, main: {…}, loaded: false, reorderCriteria: '', order: 0}
length: 2
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
 
[{…}]
0: {id: 110134, main: {…}, loaded: false, reorderCriteria: '', order: 1}
length: 1
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
```